# Is there a way to add a "For Rent" and "For Sale" listing on two different pages using AgentPress Pro?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

AgentPress Pro helps me to create a listing of all the items. But what I need to do is create two different listing pages. One "for sale" and one "for rent". Right now it is all displayed in one single page. Is there a way to show listing in two different pages ?

Comment: This might be helpful : https://sridharkatakam.com/page-templates-displaying-sale-rent-listings-agentpress-pro/

Comment: Ya, I've looked into his link but it needs signing up and we dont have payment system in Nepal :/

Comment: Add your query here : https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/agentpress-listings/